# The localStorage property does not store hyptertext reference property of an element

Tags: javascript, html, css

The `localStorage` property (`localStorage.setItem('theme', element);`) does not store the `href` property of an element (`element.href = '../assets/css/syntax-highlighting/synthwave-84.css';`):

```js
const lightButton = document.getElementById('theme-light');
const synthwaveButton = document.getElementById('theme-synthwave-84');
const body = document.body;
var check = document.getElementById('theme_css').classList[0] === 'theme-light';

const theme = localStorage.getItem('theme');
var element = document.getElementById('theme_css');

if (theme) 
{
  body.classList.add(theme);
}

synthwaveButton.onclick = () => 
{
  element.href = '../assets/css/syntax-highlighting/synthwave-84.css';
  localStorage.setItem('theme', element);

  body.classList.replace('theme-dark', 'theme-synthwave-84');
  body.classList.replace('theme-light', 'theme-synthwave-84');
  body.classList.replace('theme-cyberpunk', 'theme-synthwave-84');
  body.classList.replace('theme-tron', 'theme-synthwave-84');
  localStorage.setItem('theme', 'theme-synthwave-84');
};
```

HTML:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/syntax-highlighting/suru-plus.css" id="theme_css" />
```

Comment: try this localStorage.setItem('theme',JSON.stringify(element));

Comment: The code you show lets me assume you have copy-and-paste sections that look exactly the same for the other theme buttons. Think about how you can re-use the same function on all buttons.

Comment: @MuhammadFazeel, it does not work.

Comment: @Tomalak, yes, I am a beginner in JavaScript. Are you meanning Kerschbaumer Stefan's new implementation of re-use of the same function?

Comment: @GustavoReis That's my implementation, actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't save DOM elements to LocalStorage. LocalStorage only stores strings (that's important! you can't even store numbers or dates). Typically people store JSON if complex data needs to be saved, but here storing the theme name (which happens to be a string) is good enough.

Overall I would recommend a different approach. I'd make a single function `changeTheme()`, which takes a theme name and works the same for all themes, and use an object to store available themes and CSS paths.

```
const themes = {
  "theme-dark": "../assets/css/syntax-highlighting/dark.css",
  "theme-light": "../assets/css/syntax-highlighting/light.css",
  "theme-cyberpunk": "../assets/css/syntax-highlighting/cyberpunk.css",
  "theme-tron": "../assets/css/syntax-highlighting/tron.css",
  "theme-synthwave-84": "../assets/css/syntax-highlighting/synthwave-84.css"
};

function changeTheme(newTheme) {
  var allThemes = Object.keys(themes);
  if (!allThemes.includes(newTheme)) return;
  allThemes.forEach(theme => document.body.classList.remove(theme));
  document.body.classList.add(newTheme);
  document.getElementById('theme_css').href = themes[newTheme];
  localStorage.setItem('theme', newTheme);
}

// wire up buttons
document.querySelectorAll('.theme-switch').forEach(button => {
  button.onclick = () => changeTheme(button.id);
});

// load saved theme
changeTheme(localStorage.getItem('theme'));
```

Together with buttons like this, you'd have a working theme switcher without code duplication.

```html
<button class="theme-switch" id="theme-synthwave-84">Synthwave 84</button>
<button class="theme-switch" id="theme-tron">Tron</button>
```

Of course you can use links instead of buttons, or any other method of triggering `changeTheme()` you can think of.

Comment: I use `<a class="button" id="theme-light">Standard</a>`.

Comment: @GustavoReis That's fine, should work the same way.

Comment: @GustavoReis ...although `button` is not a good CSS class name for this, its too generic. Use a speaking CSS class like `theme-switch` to make it more obvious what it's for. When you look at the CSS file, `.button { ... }` could mean anything, it gets confusing really quickly.

Comment: Well, your code does not work. I use SCSS which will generate `schemes.css` where `.theme-light p`, `.theme-light code`, etc. and `.theme-dark p`, `.theme-dark code` . The original JavaScript will add `theme-{name-of-theme}` as a class for the `body` selector, for example: `<body class="theme-synthwave-84">`.

Comment: @GustavoReis So does my code. You might have copied it before my latest edit, but in general you should not copy code without reading and understanding every line anyway.

Comment: AH, your code works now. Before, I modified `theme-switcher` for `button` at `querySelectorAll` propeerty, then I had to to add `theme-switch` to `a` selector, together with another class `button`.

Comment: @GustavoReis Yes, that was implied. ;)

Comment: Let me ask. Is that `themes` array a JSON array? Is Object.keys(themes) a JSON key of array? Does `=>` mean as if `for` condition did?

Comment: @GustavoReis No, `themes` is an object. There is no JSON anywhere in my code. The meaning of `=>` belongs to JS fundamentals. Discussing JS fundamentals is out of scope for the comments here, I'm afraid. You say you're a beginner in JS, so I suppose you will get to the point where you'll learn about `=>` soon. You've used it yourself in your code, so I assumed you already know what it is.

Answer (score 1):

You can only store strings as values in local storage. Any objects that you want to store have to be serialised first with `JSON.stringify`. However, you can't serialise a DOM element either. Or you can, but you will just get an empty object back as all properties of DOM elements are stored on the prototype of the DOM element and `JSON.stringify` only acts on an object's own properties, so you will have to do something like:

```
localStorage.setItem('theme-css', element.href);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't save a DOM Element to the LocalStorage.
You could anyway safe the link only as a LocalStorage entry.

Comment: That's not much more than a comment right now - you should add some code to turn it into a real answer.